# What does file.new("temp.out", "w") line represent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning the Ruby language and I'm having a lot of fun.
I am currently working on the Temperature converter with file output exercise.

The solution is provided below

```
print "Hello. Please enter a Celsius value: "
celsius = gets.to_i
fahrenheit = (celsius * 9 / 5) + 32
puts "saving result to output file 'temp.out'"
```

> fh = File.new("temp.out", "w")

```
fh.puts fahrenheit
fh.close
```

The highlighted part confuses me. 
We are calling `File.new` to create a file named `"temp.out"` and `"w"` write whatever inputs until we `fh.close`. Am I correct?

Thank you!

Comment: This sort of question could have been answered by opening IRB and trying the lines. Please make IRB your first stop in figuring out how something works. You'll find you'll learn faster and better because you'll be able to experiment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `puts()` will send its output to what's called *stdout*, which is connected to your screen.  `File.new()` creates a new file which is assigned to the variable `fh`.  Because you created the file in *write mode*, you can use `fh` to write stuff to the file.  `fh.puts()` sends output to the file assigned to the variable `fh`.  In other words, a bare `puts()` statement sends output to your screen, but when you precede `puts()` with a file, the output goes to the file.

You can also write those statements like this:

```
File.open("temp.out", "w") do |f|
  f.puts fahrenheit
end
```

The neat thing about writing it like that is: when the `end` statement executes, Ruby will automatically close the file for you.

Comment: So I guess I was pretty close. Thank you for your answer. Everything is clear now!